# Improve Chrome Spellcheck

Tags: google-chrome, spell-check

How do I improve chrome's spell checking? It seems to be really really lacking basic suggestions.

[image]

I've seen there is a "Use a web service to help resolve spelling errors that says: "Google Chrome can provide smarter spell-checking **by sending what you type in the browser to Google servers**, allowing you to use the same spell-checking technology used by Google search. Learn more".

The learn more link takes you to the [following page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/114836?visit_id=1-636258156937486119-3985305027&p=settings_privacy&rd=1), which says:

"Use a web service to help resolve spelling errors: Use the same spell-checking technology in Chrome as Google Search. Chrome sends the text you typed to Google's servers."

- Does this only send what I've highlighted and right clicked? Or everything I've typed?
- Is this the **only** way to improve spell checking in chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Chrome, Settings, Show Advanced Settings, Languages, click on Language and Input Settings.  On the right, make sure "use this language for spell checking" box is checked, as well as the box below that says "enable spell checking."  As for "using a web service to resolve spelling errors," I believe everything you type is sent to Google

[settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0Z6L.png)

Comment: I dont see a  "use this language for spell checking" , though spell checking is enabled.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the window that opens when you click "Language and Input settings."  Hop that helps